# Zippex cant create file with Swedish character

Tags: attachment, encoding, zip

I have problem with Zippex encoding. When I create archive with file name 'Check Flät', the name changes to strange symbols.

Code that create attachment:

```
Zippex sampleZip = new Zippex();
Blob fileData = Blob.valueOf('Sample text.');
sampleZip.addFile('layouts/Check Flät.layout', fileData, null);

Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.Name = 'Check Flät';
attachment.ContentType = 'application/zip;charset=UTF-8;';
attachment.Body = sampleZip.getZipArchive();
attachment.Description = 'Layout';
attachment.ParentId = 'a072h000002jr3oAAA';
insert attachment;
```

What I am getting in archive:

[image]

Check Fl├дt.layout

But I want to get Check Flät.layout in name of the File.

Comment: Have you looked at the [source code of Zippex](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex) on github to identify the issue?

Comment: yes, I tried, but I do not know where it can be. Any encoding I tried, for example urlDecode/urlEncode is not working. 

Also I tried to debug this. In Zippex class all variable which can contain Name are showing right value. I think this issue in archive creating or smth.

Comment: Are you urlEncoding to ASCII or UTF8? You're probably doing the latter but you might want to do the former. This is more of an interoperability issue rather than correct encoding e.g.   https://github.com/girder/girder/issues/985 

Some other conversion techniques are described here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7368/convert-utf-8-to-ascii

Comment: @identigral I was encoding to UTF8. But I tried to do the same now with ASCII, and no result. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Checking out the [specifications](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), the file name needs to be in ASCII format. This is what's causing the problem you're seeing. To set the UTF-8 file name, you need to specify an Extra Field.

> ```
> 4.6.9 -Info-ZIP Unicode Path Extra Field (0x7075):
>
>        Stores the UTF-8 version of the file name field as stored in the
>        local header and central directory header. (Last Revision 20070912)
>
>          Value         Size        Description
>          -----         ----        -----------
>  (UPath) 0x7075        Short       tag for this extra block type ("up")
>          TSize         Short       total data size for this block
>          Version       1 byte      version of this extra field, currently 1
>          NameCRC32     4 bytes     File Name Field CRC32 Checksum
>          UnicodeName   Variable    UTF-8 version of the entry File Name
> ```

Looking at the source, I see:

```
    tempFileObject.extraFieldLength   = '0000';// (2 bytes) , creates (e)
    tempFileObject.extraField         = '';
```

Which means it's not actually attempting to set an extraField with the extended file name header. You'll need to patch Zippex to support UTF-8 file names. Aside from that, you should use **only** ASCII characters in the primary file name. I recommend you read the specs for additional information.